# OrderController of Adminhtml/Sales not properly overriden

Tags: magento-1.9, php, admin

I want to override OrderController from

```
Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/OrderController
```

In my config.xml I have written this,

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Neo_Recurring before="Mage_Adminhtml">Neo_Recurring_Adminhtml</Neo_Recurring>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

But still the controller is not getting overriden, also this is my controller definintion

```
<?php
require_once "Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php";
class Neo_Recurring_Adminhtml_OrderController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController
{
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have tried to overrider

*`Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/OrderController`*

so, you **OrderController.php** location should be  *`Neo>Recurring>controllers>Adminhtml>Sales`*

Also,you need to change the class

```
Neo_Recurring_Adminhtml_OrderController
```

**to**

```
Neo_Recurring_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to put your controller in 
For Eg.

> app/code/local/PA/Sales/controllers/Adminhtml/Sales/Order/CreateorderController.php

and **name your class accordingly.**

---

As a general rule, when rewriting a controller from ***`Mage/Adminhtml/Some/Controller/HereController.php`*** **your new path** should be `Namespace/Module/controllers/Adminhtml/Some/Controller/HereController.php`.

- So what comes after Adminhtml in the original controller should be kept after Adminhtml in your custom controller.

Comment: Thanks for info. But I have implmented same my controller is under,

Comment: app/code/local/neo/Recurring/Controllers/Adminhtml/OrderController.php

Comment: I have used this for overridding the onepage controller which is present in checkout 
require_once 'Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php';

class King_Expense_OnepageController extends  Mage_Checkout_OnepageController